# How to add table entity as serializable in Ado net in EF 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, silverlight-5.0

I am new in Ado net. I am using EF 6.

I have 2 table UserInfo and UserType.

Now when I want to get userInfo then I want to set UserTypeName to display in grid with other UserInfo and for this I have used below code.

```
public List<UserInfoBind> SearchBindUser(UserInfo objSeacrh)
        {
            try
            {                     
                List<UserInfoBind> objList = (from sql in dbContext.UserInfoes.Where(t => t.IsDelete != true)
                                              join tblType in dbContext.UserTypes
                                              on sql.UserType equals tblType.UserTypeID
                                              select new UserInfoBind()
                                               {
                                                   UserTypeName = tblType.UserTypeName
                                               }).ToList();
                return objList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

And Decalre UserInforBind as below :

```
 [DataContract]
    public class UserInfoBind : UserInfo
    {  
        public UserInfoBind()
        {

        }

        [DataMember]
        public string UserTypeName { get; set; }
    }
```

But it gives error: " Type 'DAL.UserInfoBind' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute."

So How can I make SerializableAttribute of Userinfo table entity in EF 6.
Thanks,
Hitesh Paghadal

Comment: Why do you want to mark UserInfoBind with DataContract?

Comment: I want to use this class in Wcf So I have used Datacontact. If I am wrong plz give me some guidance because I am new in Ado net EF. tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

If you want to use the same types used to represent your database model for WCF DataContract as well, then you need to mark your entity with DataContract attribute and properties with DataMember attribute. I assume you are using Database First approach, if yes, you can change the code generation template to mark all your entities with DataContract attribute and all the properties with DataMember attribute.

Another approach is to leave your database types as is and create new set of types for your DataContract(s) and use tools like AutoMapper to map the properties you need.

I prefer the second approach as it allows you to change your underlying model without affecting what is exposed via WCF service.

**Edit**: If you wan to go with editing code template then, here is how you do it

Under your EDMX file, you will see two files with .tt extension. One for data context and one for model.
    Open the one create for model and make the following changes

```
// To add DataMember attibute in all the properties
// Change


public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
    }

// To

public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "[DataMember] {0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
        _code.Escape(edmProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}

// To add DataMember attibute in all the navigation properties
// Change

public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
{
    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
        navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        _code.Escape(navProp),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
}

// TO

public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
{
    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "[DataMember] {0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
        navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        _code.Escape(navProp),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
}

// To add DataContract attibute in all the types
// Change

public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
}

// To


public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "[DataContract] {0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }


// To include System.Runtime.Serialization
// Change



public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }



  //  To



public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
{
    return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
        ? string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}using System;{1}" +
            "using System.Runtime.Serialization;{2}" +
            "{3}",
            inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
            Environment.NewLine,
            includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
            inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
        : "";
}
```

**Edit 2**: Change your select method to include all the properties from UserInfo otherwise your UserInfoBind will only have UserTypeName

```
select new UserInfoBind()
 { 
    userInfoprop1 = sql.value1,  
    userInfoprop2 = sql.value2, 
    UserTypeName = tblType.UserTypeName
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I am using Database first approach But how can I mark all entities with DataContract?

Comment: Thanks, Error  is solved but When I get data , All data is null. For Example I have 3 UserInfo data and when I get data using above function it displays 3 count but Data is null. Can I have to make any change in Linq query and UserInfoBind which I made to use in my project because currently I declare UserInfoBind calss Datacontact.

Comment: Your linq query only selects usertypename so you have null for all the properties inherited from UserInfo. Change your select to set all the properties you need.

Comment: I want all property of Userinfo and also userType So what are changes I need to do?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But Is there any short way to do this becoz I have more than 80 property in some table.